# xcorr2 VS "manual" cross-correlation

Tags: matlab, fft, offset, cross-correlation

I have written a short code that does both "manual" cross-correlation of two images and cross-correlation using `xcorr2`. The goal is to find the shift (in pixels) between both images.

I don't understand why, but both methods give me vastly different results.

The `xcorr2` method has been implemented this way :

```
clc
close all
%Cropping the bitmaps into the 2 sections I Want to cross-correlate, placing them in the center of new bitmaps with 2^n dimensions
ExpInitCrop = imcrop(BMInit,[1, 157, 1024, 131]); %Size of cropped images : 132*1024
ExpFinalCrop = imcrop(BMFinal,[1, 157, 1024, 131]);
ExpInitLarge = padarray(ExpInitCrop, [190, 512]); %Total size of both images : 512*2048
ExpFinalLarge = padarray(ExpFinalCrop, [190, 512]);

%Grayscalling the 2 sections
ExpInitLargeGS = ind2gray(ExpInitLarge, mapInit);
ExpFinalLargeGS = ind2gray(ExpFinalLarge, mapFinal);

%xcorr
tic
XCorrExp = xcorr2(ExpInitLargeGS, ExpFinalLargeGS);
toc
whos XCorrExp
mesh(XCorrExp)

%Finding shift alongside X and Y axis
[max_XCorrExp, imax] = max(abs(XCorrExp(:)));
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(XCorrExp),imax(1));
corr_offset = [(ypeak-size(ExpInitLarge,1)) (xpeak-size(ExpInitLarge,2))]
```

The xcorr2 function takes about 85-90 seconds to compute. The output matrix, XCorrExp, is 1023*4096 in size. Calculated offset is (-2, -37), which seems perfectly according to input data.

Now, the "manual" cross-correlation has been implemented using this formula : `corr(a, b) = ifft(fft(a_and_zeros) * conj(fft(b_and_zeros)))`, which is the formula for cross-correlating two signals.
Here is the code :

```
clc
close all
%Cropping the bitmaps into the 2 sections I Want to cross-correlate, placing them in the center of new bitmaps with 2^n dimensions
ExpInitCrop = imcrop(BMInit,[1, 157, 1024, 131]); %Size of cropped images : 132*1024
ExpFinalCrop = imcrop(BMFinal,[1, 157, 1024, 131]);
ExpInitLarge = padarray(ExpInitCrop, [190, 512]); %Total size of both images : 512*2048
ExpFinalLarge = padarray(ExpFinalCrop, [190, 512]);

tic
%Grayscalling the 2 sections
ExpInitLargeGS = ind2gray(ExpInitLarge, mapInit);
ExpFinalLargeGS = ind2gray(ExpFinalLarge, mapFinal);

%FFT
ExpInitFFT = fft2(ExpInitLargeGS);
ExpFinalFFT = fft2(ExpFinalLargeGS);

%Conjugating complex values
for i = 1:size(ExpFinalFFT,1)
    for j = 1:size(ExpFinalFFT,2)
        ExpFinalFFT(i,j) = conj(ExpFinalFFT(i,j));
    end
end

%Element-wise multiplication
ExpMultipliedMatrix = times(ExpInitFFT, ExpFinalFFT);

%IFFT
XCorrExp = ifft2(ExpMultipliedMatrix);
XCorrExpShift = fftshift(XCorrExp);
toc
whos XCorrExpShift
mesh(XCorrExpShift)

%Finding shift alongside X and Y axis
[max_XCorrExpShift, imax] = max(abs(XCorrExpShift(:)));
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(XCorrExpShift),imax(1));
corr_offset = [(ypeak-size(ExpInitLarge,1)) (xpeak-size(ExpInitLarge,2))]
```

The "manual" method takes about 0.7-0.8 seconds to compute. The output matrix, XCorrExpShift, is 512*2048 in size. Calculated offset is (-257, -1060), which seems WAY, WAY off according to the input data.

I have a hard time understanding why my "manual" method doesn't give the same results as the `xcorr2` method. Is someone able to explain this to me ? What does `xcorr2` do that my manual method doesn't ?

Thanks !

EDIT : the expected output would be the same offset as the one given by the `xcorr2` method. But I would also like to understand why thre is such i huge difference in computing time.
[image: Here is the first input bitmap]
[image: Here is the second]

Comment: Please give us a [MCVE] (notably including input and its expected output)

Comment: @Wolfie It's done !